# Stack or LinkedList for ObjectPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, object-pooling

I'm sure the correct answer to this depends on the type of pooled objects and the workload, so I'll detail my implementation a bit:

I have an ObjectPool used to pool long-running command-line processes. These processes communicate via stdin/stdout, and perform file/network operations. Many tasks complete much faster than others and may return processes to the pool quickly. All access to the pool must be thread-safe.

My question is, am I better off managing the pool with a LIFO/Stack, or a FIFO/ConcurrentLinkedQueue? My reasoning on both sides:

- A stack keeps "hot" objects in play, where resources may remain cached/etc. for longer.
- A FIFO balances calls more evenly between the processes, with each doing less work. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could use a [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and combine the best of both worlds.

Comment: So each process is specialized on something or they can all do the same thing?

Comment: @Tudor: All can do the same thing. Any object is as good as the next to the borrow()er.

Comment: @Jeffrey: What is the advantage to using this over a Stack? Just so I can "try both ways" easily, or better concurrency?

Comment: @Will `Stack` is based off of `Vector`, which might as well be [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated). This will allow you to mix and match the two approaches, it can be both FIFO and LIFO.

Comment: A [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) uses a wait-free algorithm that would make it faster than the ConcurrentLinkedDeque. One reason (perhaps a poor one) to prefer the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was: **benchmark it**! Both of your arguments seem reasonable. You should implement both strategies and do tests which of them results in the higher throughput.

The problem you describe in your question is similar to the process scheduling operating systems have to face. Hence, maybe it would be useful to make use of priorities. Use a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and assign different priorities to your tasks, which could change dynamically over time, for instance with [Aging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aging_%28scheduling%29).

And last but not least, as was already pointed out in the comments you could try both [ConcurrentLinkDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and let some fetch the front objects and some the rear objects. Here, too, my advice is to try out and measure which balancing works best.

Answer (score 1):

It might not make a performance difference.  Do whatever is easiest to code and makes your code easy to understand.  A cache miss here and there isn't going to make a difference when you are dealing with command line processes doing file and network I/O... those are going to dominate by orders of magnitude.